# Fitting a constrained dose-response log-logistic curve

Tags: r, constraints, drc

I have dose-response data I'd like to fit a log-logistic curve for.

Here's the data:

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c(10,0.625,2.5,0.15625,0.0390625,0.00244140625,0.009765625,0.0006103515625,10,0.625,2.5,0.15625,0.0390625,0.00244140625,0.009765625,0.0006103515625,10,0.625,2.5,0.15625,0.0390625,0.00244140625,0.009765625,0.0006103515625),
                 response=c(0.990196078431373,0.841175218686903,0.756728767942187,0.650910609644933,0.845425185365378,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.990196078431373,0.544378228848476,0.815621363298204,0.810605311840132,0.990196078431373,0.783062670405492,0.761774545153645,0.720957414865623,0.917229218695802))
```

Fitting a `drc` `LL4` model:

```
require(drc)
fit <- drm(response~dose,data=df,fct=LL.4(names=c("slope","low","high","ED50")))
```

and plotting it using predicted data:

```
new.data <- expand.grid(dose=exp(seq(log2(max(df$dose)),log2(min(df$dose)),length=100)))
pred <- predict(fit,newdata=new.data,interval="confidence")
points(log2(new.data$dose),pred[,1],type="l")
```

I get:
[image]

However, I think a better fit should look like:
[image]

The reason is that the single point at the highest dose is much smaller than all other points, and strongly indicates a low response there.

Clearly, there's a lot of noise in these data. One of them is that all the points exactly at response=1.0 were originally higher (due to batch corrections) but pushed down since a response > 1 is meaningles in my case.

The same happens for points with response < 0 (set to 0) although this data set doesn't have any of that.

My question is how do I get such a fitted curve? If this is by contraining `drm`, what should these contraints be?

Comment: Something is wrong with your data. Do you see all these constant values just below 1? Fitting anything to this data and expecting a sensible result is a lost cause.

Comment: I think you are approaching this with too fixed an opinion on what the result should look like. Except for that single data point at log2(dose_=3, there is absolutely nothing to indicate that the dose-response curve looks the way you think it should. The fit drm gave you is entirely reasonable. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I edited my question to address these points.